# very simple XMLHttpRequest not working

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm practicing XmlHttpRequest, and I'm trying to run basic Javascript that will get the data stored in a text file. Here's my Javascript:

```
var xml = XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open("GET", "setverfile.txt",true);
xml.send(null);
alert(xml.responseText);
```

And my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

        <title>XMLHttpRequest</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="XMLHttpRequest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

textfile:

```
This is a textfile resideing on a server
```

When I try running the code, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: setverfile is in the same folder as XMLHttpRequest.js ? Is it a valid XML file?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're missing your [onreadystatechange]

When you send an Ajax request, you need to listen for the state change.

Your code is asynchronous, hence listening for state change is required.
xml.open("GET", "setverfile.txt",true); // The true parametter is for async

If you did
xml.open("GET", "setverfile.txt",false); // The false parametter is for non async.

Then your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

In my testing, it seems that all you were missing was the `new` keyword:

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
```